# Play Framework2.6のドキュメントがほしい

Tags: java, playframework, java8

現在Java、Play Frameworkで開発しています。
**PlayFramework2.6のドキュメントがほしいなと思うのですが、どこにありますでしょうか？

また、オススメや初心者なのでわかりやすいのがあれば嬉しいなと思っています。**

こちらは確認できているのですが、変更点の説明が多く、もっとこのフレームワークのAPIを投げるまでの一連のフローとかがわかる基礎的な説明があるものがほしいです。
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Highlights26

１系から２系で大きく変わったと聞きましたので、１系の説明を勉強するより２系の基本を学んだほうがいいのかなとも思っています。

詳しい方がいればよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorials ではどうですか？
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Tutorials
一つ古い 2.6.x は以下にあるようです。
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Tutorials

Comment: ありがとうございます！確認します